# For a char[] of size 20, if i enter char from char[0] to char[7], and i write the char[] to a file, does it take up 20 bytes or 8 bytes on the disk?

Tags: c++, arrays

Here is a sample code

```
char text[20];
fstream file("temp.dat",ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out|ios::app);
cout<<"Enter the text: "<<endl;
cin>>text; //assuming text entered is elephant

// file write operation
file.write((char*)(&text),sizeof(text));
// file write operation done
```

so if the char array of size 20 is storing the word "elephant"(char[0] to char[7]) which is 8 characters long, what is stored in the rest of the char[] starting from char[8] to char[19]? does this text take 8 bytes on the disk or does it take up 20 bytes on the disk since char[] is 20 bytes in size?

Comment: on windows, this file would take up a single mft record entry of 1024 bytes on the disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use sizeof, it takes all the array, with \0 where there is no text. You could use `strlen` to limit to the length of the sting.

All this C-like approach however is bad. Lots of overruns, under runs, serialization issues etc. Use `std::string` instead. In Windows you also want Unicode text.

Comment: yes i was having issues with serialization of a char[]. could you show me how to serialize a char [] in c++? and thanks for answering my question!

Answer (score 4):

> "elephant"(char[0] to char[7]) which is 8 characters long

"elephant" is actually 9 characters long when one remembers to count the null terminator character.

> what is stored in the rest of the char[] starting from char[8] to char[19]?

They would remain unmodified by the stream extraction operation. If they were not initialised before, then they remain uninitialised i.e. they would have indeterminate value.

> Does this text take 8 bytes on the disk or does it take up 20 bytes on the disk since char[] is 20 bytes in size?

The second argument of write is the number of chars that you write. You passed `sizeof(text)` i.e. 20, therefore you wrote 20 chars.

That's the size of the file. How much space that takes on disk depends on the file system.

Comment: That answered all my questions! Thank you so much!

Comment: If i wanted to save disk space and just write the length of char[] till '\0'character that is till char[9] then each time i would write a text to the file it would take up different space depending on the size of the text. so i would have problems reading file if i entered wrong length to read. is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

> if the char array of size 20 is storing the word "elephant"(char[0] to char[7]) which is 8 characters long

9 actually, if you count the null terminator at `char[8]`.

> what is stored in the rest of the char[] starting from char[8] to char[19]?

That content is *indeterminate*, since you are not initializing the array with any data before reading into the array, and reading a word that is less than the array size does not populate the unused portions of the array.

Also, you are not specifying the size of the array when reading, so you have a potential buffer overflow waiting to happen.  Imagine what would happen if the user typed in a word that has 20+ characters in length.  `cin` would not know when to stop reading, so it would overflow the buffer into surrounding memory.  So, you should be using `cin`'s [`get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) method instead:

```
cin.get(text, sizeof(text));
```

Or, if you want the text to allow spaces, the [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) method:

```
cin.getline(text, sizeof(text));
```

`get()`/`getline()` ensures the read does not exceed the buffer, and the output is null-terminated (truncating the text if needed) . `cin.gcount()` will tell you how many characters were actually read.

Or better, use a `std::string` instead:

```
string text;
cin >> text; // or: getline(cin, text);
```

This will ensure the full word (or line) is read, regardless of its length.

> does this text take 8 bytes on the disk or does it take up 20 bytes on the disk since char[] is 20 bytes in size?

20 bytes will be written to the file <sup>1</sup>, because that is how many bytes you are telling `write()` to write (`sizeof(text)`), regardless of the array's actual content.

<sup>1: the actual number of bytes the file takes up on disk depends on multiple factors: the particular filesystem being used, whether the file is sparse or compressed, etc. But lets just assume a simple filesystem with no sparcity/compression. The file will take up however many bytes you write, rounded up to an even multiple of the disk's cluster size, plus overhead for tracking metdata about the file.</sup>

If you want to write only to the end of the text that was read, and not to the end of the array, then you would need something more like this instead:

```
char text[20] = {};
fstream file("temp.dat", ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out|ios::app);
cout << "Enter the text: " << endl;
cin.get(text, sizeof(text)); // or: cin.getline(text, sizeof(text));

// file write operation
file.write(text, cin.gcount()/*or: strlen(text)*/);
// file write operation done
```

Or better:

```
string text;
fstream file("temp.dat", ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out|ios::app);
cout << "Enter the text: " << endl;
cin >> text; // or: getline(cin, text);

// file write operation
file << text; // or: file.write(text.c_str(), text.size());
// file write operation done
```

Comment: Very detailed and perfect answer. Thank you @Remy Lebeau. So if i wanted to read the file and just display the text how would i know where a particular text i entered ends so i can read only to that point and next read would be the next text on the file? assuming there are multiple lines of text written in the file.

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma The `istream::get()` I demonstrated reads until a line break is reached (or the text buffer is full). There is an overload of `get()` where you can specify a delimiter to stop at. Otherwise, you can use `>>` (with `std::setw` to avoid overflow) to read into a `char[]` until whitespace is reached. Though you really should use `std::string` instead, then `>>` "just works" exactly as you ask for.